# Overwriting Update to either Update or Archive in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My requirement is that I want an object (tee) to update if there have not been rounds played on it. If there have been rounds played on it then I want the object (tee) to archive (active attribute set to false) and the updates to be applied to a clone of the object.

My first thought was that I would overwrite the update method in the Tee model like so and have a private method that handles the archive, clone and change:

```
def update
  if(self.rounds.count == 0)
    super
  else
    #archive, clone and apply changes
    archive_clone_and_change
    return false
  end
end
```

This feels dirty though because I am returning a false on a successful archive update. It also is going to get tricky when I try to apply the changes in the archive_clone_and_change method.

Should I be doing this in the controller instead of the method or does my approach make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model vs. Controller decisions,  they can get subjective,  but I would to it in the controller.  It's really logic being applied to the model,  not directly related to the model itself.

Comment: Thanks..the more time I spend thinking about this the more I think you are right. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.